# Execute one subscription after another one (in order)

Tags: angular

I have 3 components: FilterComponent, MonthSliderComponent and ChartComponent.

The CharComponent is updated when the FilterComponent or the MonthSliderComponent change by subscribing to both.

The MonthSliderComponent is also subscribed to FilterComponent. I use ReplaySubject for it. There's no problem if I stay in the same page and I change the filter or the monthSlider.

But there are other pages where the FilterComponent and the MonthSliderComponent are used too, and when I change them and I come back to the page with the ChartComponent both subscriptions are executed. The MonthSliderComponent is executed first but I need FilterComponent to be first. Is there any way to manage this?

My code:

```
@Injectable()
export class FilterService {
    ...
    filterReplaySubject: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);
    ...
}


@Injectable()
export class MonthSliderService {
    ...
    monthSliderReplaySubject: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);
    ...   
}


@Component({
    ...
})
export class MonthSliderComponent implements ngOnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscripcion: Subscription;

    constructor(private filterService: FilterService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscripcion = this.filterVm.filterReplaySubject
        .subscribe(params => {
            ...
        }); 
    }
}


@Component({
    ...
})
export class ChartComponent implements ngOnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscripcion: Subscription;

    constructor(private filterService: FilterService,
        private monthSliderService MonthSliderService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscripcion = this.filterVm.filterReplaySubject
        .subscribe(params => {
            ...
        });

        this.subscripcion.add(this.monthSliderVm.monthSliderSubject
        .subscribe(params => {
            ...
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the same instance of those components, put the shared components into a shared module, and export them from the shared module,

then import the shared module into the modules you want to have access to the components. This will create separate instances of those components, and the logic will only access those instances